# Linux Mint - adding environment variables permanently

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, linux-mint

I was trying to modify the ~/.profile file to add a line to the PATH variable. I added this line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/paul/avatar-gf-1.0-ea/glassfish4/bin/
```

at the end. I restarted the terminal, but it still did not identify commands in that directory. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: This is what I get if I "echo $PATH": /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/paul/jdk1.8.0/bin/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this in the ~/.pam_environment in your home folder. If it does not exist then create it:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/home/paul/avatar-gf-1.0-ea/glassfish4/bin/
```

You will need to log in and out.

Comment: I edited it slightly as per the Ubuntu website you should now set session variables in ~/.pam_environment see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 7):

Run `bash -xl` to see which startup files are loaded with your shell. `.profile` may actually not be read. Otherwise try adding `export` to your assignment:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/paul/avatar-gf-1.0-ea/glassfish4/bin/
```

Reference about Bash's startup files: *[Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)*

Comment: Thanks, but bash -xl lists the .profile file the export command doesn't change the situation.

Comment: @user2816783 Try to add `hash -r` after that line.

Comment: And make sure that those binary files are executable.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 18.3 [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)). The changes in file *~/.profile* got picked up only after I logged out/in from the account. The terminal restart was not enough in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you edit the *.bashrc* file,

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

you will see the next line

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

So create a *~/.bash_aliases* file in your $HOME folder and add any command you want to be executed when you open the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You may add an entry to the *~/.pam_environment* file.

1. Use any editor to access the file. I am using the default Linux Mint *Text Editor* (xed).

   ```
   xed ~/.pam_environment
   ```
2. That file is likely to have some entries already. Add a new line to the file and add your entry.
   For example, I am adding a java binary path which is in the *opt* folder to the **$PATH** environment variable:

   ```
   PATH    DEFAULT=${PATH}:/opt/JDK11/jdk-11.0.2/bin`
   ```

   Or if you want to add a path  that is in the user home or something like that, then do like:

   ```
   PATH    DEFAULT=${PATH}:/home/@{PAM_USER}/MyPrograms`
   ```
3. Save the file. It should work. If it doesn't, log out, log back in and try again. If it doesn't work even after that, then restart and try again and it will work for sure. :)