# How can I change the default python packages accesible to git in vscode?

Tags: python-3.x, git, visual-studio-code

I am working on a commit-msg git hook.  Everything works except importing of specific modules.  The bad behaviour is specific to the use of the vs-code GUI git bar (little check mark at the top of the source control panel) with pip installed modules.  If I use `git commit -m "some message"` through the terminal, everything works perfectly.
But, when I use the vs-code GUI, I get an import error.

Thinking it may be an environment issue, I ensured that the module needed was available globally by `pip install`ing the needed module to my machine outside of any virtual environment.  It didn't help.

To see what's going on, I wiped my hook and replaced it with nothing more than `help("modules")` to see if my modules were indeed there.  They were not.  So I ran

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(dir_path)
```

This printed my path to the file being ran and was the path expected.
I opened a new terminal outside of vs-code with no virtual environment enabled and ran `python3 path/to/file` to see if my module would show up there.  It did.

Additionally, it is there if I run it in the vs-code terminal as well.  The only place it seems to be missing is wherever the vs-code git GUI pulls it's package list from.

Where does vs-code git get it python package list and how can I ensure that either; 1) it points to my normal python package list or 2) I can add the needed modules into it's path?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Thanks to the intelligent suggestion of John Szakmeister left in the comments, I have configured my hook to call env.  I then initiated the hook through the terminal and through the GUI to compare.

Using the GUI adds a few variables, mostly for logging purposes and error handling.  But there are a couple that I don't quite know what they do.  `APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL=true` and
`ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1`

However, being that it works in terminal but not GUI, I have to assume that the added variables are not the culprit.  So, instead I look at what is different from one to the other.
Outside of the additional VS-Code specific variables, there really isn't very much that is coming up different.

Shell level is 2 through terminal but only 1 through the GUI (interesting...)
Terminal has extra variables `TERM=xterm-256color` and `TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=1.46.0` that aren't present in GUI env.
Additionally, there are some colors that are set in terminal but not the GUI.

Lastly, there is one variable that is in both that is different.  GUI gives `_=/usr/share/code/code` while terminal yields `_=/usr/bin/git`.  I assume that these refer to what program initiated the terminal but I haven't been able to verify that.

That's about it.  `PATH` is the same for both, as is `SHELL`, as are just about all of the `GIT_anything` variables (outside of the fact that the GUI sets a pager that the terminal does not)

Comment: It sounds very much like an environment issue.  Which platform are you on?  Linux?  macOS?

Comment: @John Running linux-mint 5.3.0-59-generic, Visual Studio Code 1.46.0, git version 2.17.1

Comment: You probably want to look at this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013725/linux-mint-adding-environment-variables-permanently  My guess is that you're launching vscode from the GUI, so it doesn't pick up any environment variables you've set in .bashrc.  Setting them in ~/.pam_environment, as suggested in the linked answer, should make it available to all programs.  Also, have you tried doing something like making the commit hook call env and printing that out to view from vscode or saving it to a file?  It might help give you a better idea of what is going on.